# Входные данные из файла в список. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
4
0 0 1 1
0 -1 0 1
4 2 1 0
3 3 8 -1
3
0 1 3 2
0 -1 3 -2
2 1 3 -1
2
0 0 2 0
2 1 3 4
```

Есть вот такие входные данные из файла input.txt. Как считать их из файла в список вида:

```
[ [[4], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, -1, 0, 1], [4, 2, 1, 0], [3, 3, 8, -1]], [[3], ...], [[2], ...] ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

а в чем проблема то? как считать из файла или как сформировать такой массив?

решайте задачу в лоб, если трудности:

0. создается пустой массив `res = []`
1. файл считывается построчно
2. каждая строка распарсивается в массив чисел

   ```
   line = map(int, text.split())
   ```
3. и заносится во временный массив

   ```
    tmp.append(line)
   ```
4. если считанная строка содержит лишь одно число - временный массив заносится в результирующий и очищается

   ```
    if len(line) == 1:
        res.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
   ```

Comment: Проблема была в составлении массива.

Comment: @Kirill Stepankov, тогда в лоб как я написал :)

Comment: Cпасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    arr = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line) == 1:
            arr.append([int(line[0])])
        else:
            arr[-1].append(list(map(int, line)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.